# Implementing a strength powerup into Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am currently in the process of implementing a strength powerup into my game. The powerup is within its own scene and will emit a signal into the enemy script if the player collides with it. Without the powerup, the player has to individually attack the enemy 4 times (i.e. one hit reduces one life, the enemy has 4 lives). I wish for the strength powerup to increase the damage from 1, to 2 - so the player only has to attack the enemy 2 times.

The below function handles the collision between the player's sword and the enemy's hurtbox.

```
func _on_Hurtbox_area_entered(area): # called when there is a collision between players sword and enemy
    if area.is_in_group("Sword"):
        damage(1) 
        flash()
```

This function will then call the damage function.

```
func damage(damage_dealt):
    var damage_n = damage_dealt # stores the parameter as a new local variable
    lives -= damage_n # removes enemy life
    if lives < 1: # no lives
        dead()
```

The signal currently links to a function called `powerup_damage`.

Essentially, I am unsure of how to call the `damage` function, from the `_on_Hurtbox_area_entered` function with a `damage_dealt` value of 2, only when the powerup has been collected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering the question as posted.**

> The powerup is within its own scene and will emit a signal into the enemy script if the player collides with it.

*This is very odd to me. You are telling me that the power-up does not make the player stronger, but instead it makes the enemies weaker. OK.*

You are going to another signal for when the power up ends. So you can have a variable that you set to `true` when the player gets the power up, and to `false` when it ends. Then you can check if the variable is `true` and use that to decide the value of the damage.

*I'm giving this solution to answer the question as posted. Yet, I would like to encourage another approach.*

---

**Another approach**

The other approach I want to encourage has this goal: Don't have the enemy calling damage on itself.

Instead, you would have the sword call damage on the enemy. The enemy would then not need any information about what power-ups the player has. Instead all the power up code would be on the player (and sword) side. Which also means that:

- Every time you add a new enemy kind, you don't need to make sure it has the power-up logic.
- Every time you add a new power-up, you don't need to make sure every enemy kind has the logic for it.

Currently the sword already has an area. For the change I'm suggesting, you could could have that area detect when the hurtbox enters, instead of having the hurtbox detect when the sword area enters.

---

Presumably you would not need any power-up signal. Since this approach does not require to notify the enemies that the player picked a power-up.

---

By the way, the damage function does not need to take the actual damage, in fact, I would argue it should not.

Instead have it take an attack value, or even more parameters. Let the code on the enemy compute how much damage that actually is. That allows you to have some enemies more resistant than others, without having the code on the sword depending on the enemy exposing variables for the computation.

And yes, you could pass what power-ups the player has, and let the enemy use that information to compute the actual damage (that allows you to have enemies that ignore the power-up).

*Furthermore, if the damage parameters get too complex, you can always make an resource class, and pass an object of that class. You can even reuse the object for identical attacks.*